# I am able to access dataArray from view controller file but having an error Fatal error: Index out of range?

Tags: arrays, swift, fatal-error

This is my code I am able to download data from API and data is also stored in dataArray but if this array is accessed from another view controller or within this class only it shoes error.
import Foundation
import Alamofire

```
class DashboardData {
    struct User {

        var StateName: String
        var schemes: Int
        var trainingCenter: Int
        var DDSubmitted: Int
        var ddApproved:Int
        var trainingBatches: Int
        var ongoingBatches : Int
        var closedBatches: Int
        var trainingCandidates: Int
        var underTraining: Int
        var droppedOut: Int
        var trained: Int
        var placements: Int
        var totalJobs: Int
        var consideredPlaced:Int
        var averageSalary:Int

        init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
            self.StateName = dictionary["StateName"] as? String ?? ""
            self.schemes = dictionary["No_of_scheme"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.trainingCenter = dictionary["Training_Centres_Proposed_by_OPS"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.DDSubmitted = dictionary["DD_done"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.ddApproved = dictionary["DD_approved"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.trainingBatches = dictionary["Total_Batches_till_Date"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.ongoingBatches = dictionary["Batches_in_Progress"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.closedBatches = dictionary["Closed_Batches"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.trainingCandidates = dictionary["Candidates_Enrolled"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.underTraining = dictionary["Candidates_Under_Training"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.droppedOut = dictionary["Candidates_Dropped_out"]as? Int ?? 0
            self.trained = dictionary["Candidates_Trained"]as? Int ?? 0
            self.placements = dictionary["Total_interviews"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.totalJobs = dictionary["Total_offered_jobs"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.consideredPlaced = dictionary["Consider_placed"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.averageSalary = dictionary["Average_salary"]as? Int ?? 0
        }
    }


    var dataArray = [User]()

    func downloadData(){
        let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard
        let userID = defaultValues.string(forKey: "userid")
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.241:9011/api/\(userID!)")
        //`print(url!)
        // credentials
        let user = "***"
        let password = "***"
        let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

        Alamofire.request(url!,
                          method: .get,
                          parameters: nil,
                          encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                          headers:headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let result = response.result.value{
                    print(result)
                    let jsonArray = result as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]

                    for dic in jsonArray{
                      //  model.append(User(dic))// adding now value in Model array
                        self.dataArray.append(User(dic))// adding now value in dataArray
                    }
                    print(self.dataArray[0].StateName)
           }else{
                    print("Error")
                }

    }
```

if i do//print(self.dataArray[0].StateName) here xcode shows error
    }
could any one expalin me where i am lagging?

Comment: Your code formatting is broken, can you fix it please? It is unclear now where you call `self.dataArray[0].StateName`

Comment: Is `jsonArray` empty?

Comment: Unrelated but a JSON dictionary is never `[String:AnyObject]` in Swift 3+  it's always `[String:Any]`

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(result)` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your `jsonArray` is empty for some reason and it makes your `dataArray` to stay empty as well. To avoid this error replace your print line with with

```
print(self.dataArray.first?.StateName)
```

or this for more informative log

```
if self.dataArrat.isEmpty {
    print("Data array is empty")
} else {
    // now we can be sure that our array has at leat one element
    print(self.dataArray[0].StateName)
}
```

Comment: `if let stateName = dataArray.first?.StateName {
    print("State name:", stateName)
}`

Comment: @yury imashev i know the array is empty but my question is who can i set json value to my variables and use them outside the alamofire request?

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi If I got you right, your problem is that when you're trying to access your array, your app crashes. And it crashes because you're trying to print the value of the `first` element when your array is empty and has `0` elements. In my answer, I show how you can access elements when you're not sure if the array is empty.